# Stop outlook from automatically deleting items

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I use the "Deleted Items" folder in Outlook 2010 as an archive, so I want all my deleted items to stay in this folder.

However, every so often (ever 2 weeks, maybe?), I can see some items from this folder has been (permenantly) deleted - I can put them back using the "Recover Deleted Items" functionality - but I'm affraid that if I forget to do this, they will some day actually be **permenantly** deleted...

Is there a way to stop Outlook from doing this? I an connected to an Exchange Server 2003 mail server. Or is this an Exchange task doing this on the server?

And it is **not** the Auto Archive functionality from Outlook that is doing this. I've disabled that a long time ago...

Comment: Do you also store things in the trash can at home?

Comment: No - but from an iPhone, the new mail app in Windows 8 etc. there's a "build in" delete button, which is a single click to "archive"... Having to move the message to another folder involves multiple clicks and perhaps even some scrolling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that sounds like it could be a mailbox policy from the exchange server. to work around this, you should really be moving your files that you intend to keep as archive into a special folder just for them.